# How to identify periods of high variance in temporal data

Tags: time-series, variance

I have a dataset with concentration of a chemical (continuous) as the dependent variable plotted against time (continuous). I expect that certain periods during the year (e.g. summer) will have relatively higher variance than other periods of the year. Is there a way to identify periods of significantly high variance?

Answer (score 0):

Take a rolling standard deviation (i.e. Using a fixed sample size, and move the window through your dataset. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/595541

Comment: I have multiple samples that were sampled at same time, to use a rolling standard deviation would I not have to the mean at each sampling time? In which case I think I would be losing information concerning variance?

Comment: I see. How about taking the 5th and 95th percentiles of each sample